# Is it okay to make my affiliate links look like google adsense ads and place above or below them?

Tags: google-adsense

I have seen on a few websites/themes eg (http://www.adsensepress.com/maxctr-wordpress-theme) which put content above or below the adsense ads and make them look like the ads. Is that acceptable? I read the Adsense TOS and it doesn't say explicitly anywhere that it is not.

Comment: Similar question: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/18525/blog-suitable-adsense-format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I found the answer here.

http://www.google.com/adsense/support/bin/answer.py?answer=32849

> You're welcome to display Google ads on the same site or page as other
>   third party advertisements provided that the formatting or colors of
>   the third party ads is different enough from that of the Google ads.
>   In other words, if you choose to place non-Google ads on the same site
>   or page as Google ads, it should always be clear to the user that the
>   ads are served by different advertising networks and that the
>   non-Google ads have no association with Google. If the formats are
>   naturally similar, we ask that you choose different color schemes for
>   the competing ads.

Its not okay to make any ads look like google adsense ads.